# Null Pointer Exception in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a Java file, but when I do I get an error `NullPointerException` in this part of the program.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class HiveClient {
   // JDBC driver required for Hive connections
   private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
   private static Connection con;

   private static Connection getConnection(String ip, String port, String user, String password) {
      try {
         // dynamically load the Hive JDBC driver
         Class.forName(driverName);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         return null;
      } // try catch

      try {
         // return a connection based on the Hive JDBC driver
         return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://" + ip + ":" + port + "/default?user=" + user + "&password=" + password);

      } catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         return null;
      } // try catch
   } // getConnection

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         // from here on, everything is SQL!
         con = getConnection("130.206.80.46", "10000", "myuser", "mypasswd");
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select column1,column2,otherColumns " + "from mytable where column1='whatever' and columns2 like '%whatever%'");

         // iterate on the result
         while (res.next()) {
            String column1 = res.getString(1);
            Integer column2 = res.getInt(2);

            // whatever you want to do with this row, here
         } // while

         // close everything
         res.close();
         stmt.close();
         con.close();

      } catch (SQLException ex) {
         System.exit(0);
      } // try catch
   }
    // doQuery
} // HiveClient
```

This is the message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at HiveClient.main(HiveClient.java:34)
Java Result: 1
```

The line the exception is at:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

I've checked the `java.sql.Connection` package and `createStatement()` is allowed in the Method Summary.

Comment: post your stack trace and add other relevant codes

Comment: What does the method getConnection ? The first thing you must do to handle a NPE is track the origin of the null variable.

Comment: Show your getConnection method.

Comment: You probably got no connection, or some driver problems, buy the amount of information You supplied is insufficient. Give us the exception  message ad stacktrace.

go with:
try{
con = getConnection("130.206.80.46", "10000", "myuser", "mypasswd");
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: Which is line 34 in your code?

Comment: it is con.createStatement();

Comment: Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

Comment: don't return null in your getConnection method, since clearly your calling code does not expect it.  Instead, throw an exception with a decent message.

Comment: Are you sure the connection is established?

Comment: M.Sharma, no I'm not. I'm using Netbeans and I just get that msg, it doesn't run.

Comment: make sure your host allows remote connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's apply some *logic* to the problem.

Q:  Why is the NPE being thrown by that statement?

A:  The only possible explanation is that `con` has the value `null`.

Q:  Why does `con` have the value `null`.

A:  The only explanation is that this statement is assigning `null` to `con`:

```
        con = getConnection("130.206.80.46", "10000", "myuser", "mypasswd");
```

And that means that `getConnection` returns `null`.

Q:  Why is `getConnection` returning `null`.

A:  Look at the code for that method.  There two places where it *explicitly* returns `null`.  First is when `Class.forName(driverName)` throws a `ClassNotFoundException`.  Second is when `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` throws an `SQLException`.  In all other cases, it will return a non-null value.  (Read the javadocs ...)

Q:  So which is it?

A:  Look at the code!  Note that in both places where `null` is returned, you wrote a message to standard output.  That message will answer your question!!

---

The reason you are getting into trouble here is that you are catching exceptions too soon, and returning `null` as a "remedy".  It is that `null` that is causing the ultimate problem.

The *correct* way to implement this is to change the declaration for `getConnection` to say that it throws `ClassNotFoundException` and `SQLException`.  Then remove the handlers for those exceptions in `getConnection` and handle them in `main` instead.  And when you do handle them, make sure that you output (or log) the stack traces ... to make it easier to diagnose the real cause of your problems.

---

(To the authors of some of the other answers:  Debugging should not be a matter of *guessing* what the problem is.  You should look at the evidence, and draw *logical* conclusions from that evidence.  When the evidence points to *multiple* possible causes, consider them all.  Guesswork is at best a shortcut.  At worst, it will cause you to waste lots of time pursuing "theories" that *cannot possibly be true*.)

Comment: very nice suggestion for resolving issue (evidence-logical conclusion-multiple causes).
  Thank you !

Comment: What a beautiful explanation! Thank you so much @Stephen!

Answer (score 1):

Your `getConnection()` method should never print out the exception and then return `null`. It should simply throw an exception, if the driver cannot be found or (for some reason) be successfully loaded. Your code doesn't check at all if the result of `getConnection()` is `null` and this would lead to a `NullPointerException`. What would make sense to check, would be to see if you have the respective JDBC driver on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if your driver is successfully loaded and registered, also check if driver is in your classpath.
make it a habit to have a null check before using references like Connection.

Comment: hi! in my classpath? I import the package, do I have to download it too?

Comment: the location of the XXXdriver.jar should be present in your classpath.
if you can import it that means you already have it locally.

Comment: since you are not getting ClassNotFoundException for your driver class, it means your driver is in your classpath. try debug and see if you are getting Conncetion reference from DriverManager.getConnection(...)

Comment: You're right, the problem is in the driver, because it doesn't go to the first try, it runs catch instead

Answer (score 0):

try to get connection using this sway

```
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://" + ip + ":" + port+ "/default", user, password);
```

Comment: Could you explain what was wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out what was helpful to me.
I added and extra permition to onCreate method of my activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Database and make sure that first column of your SQLquery is not null. i had same issue because my first column of SQLquery was null in DB. so these exception may occur that first column in your SQLquery is null in DB, and dont try to add null column of DB in SQLquery. i hope this might helped you.

Prabhu MD

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:// localhost:PORT/DBName", "mysql", "mysql");
```

Comment: He is not using mysql.